# Running the Gitlab runner on Windows with a shell executor is not in daemon mode

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

How to run gitlab runner on windows with shell executor not in daemon mode?

The setting in the config.toml file

```
[[runners]]
  name = "windows gitlab runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  daemon = false
```

did not help

I didn't find any information in the official documentation gitlab

Comment: what do you mean not run it in daemon mode? how are you expecting it to run? and the property daemon is not a property of runners so of course this wouldnt help. https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section

Comment: For ci/cd, I registered gitlab runner on my windows machine and selected it as shell executor. Through gitlab ci, I run tests on selenium python. By default, the runner runs in the background in daemon mode, but I need to see the scripts running on my machine. To do this, it is probably necessary that the runner is not executed in daemon mode

Comment: The runner needs to run in the back ground to be able to poll the gitlab server to check for any new jobs and to manage and orchestrate the jobs it it's running

Comment: Thanks, I get it. It turns out that the tasks themselves can only work in the background?